# Странное поведение URL у Apache2

Tags: url

Здравствуйте. Проект на Yii.
Есть OnlineRequestController.php и actionCheck.
Т.е. обращаюсь по адресу: site/OnlineRequest/Check
Но получаю 404, т.к. он "лезет": /OnlineRequest.**js**/Check - откуда .js? Такой файл там действительно лежит в корне, но почему он к нему обращается?
В конфигах ничего сверхъестественного. Просто прячется index.php из пути.
Надо добавить, что сервер Apache2 на Ubuntu настроенный час назад. На другом компе норм работает. Тут скорее интерес. Есть у кого какие мысли?

Конфиг URL в config/main.php:

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>true,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

.htaccess :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Такой файл там действительно лежит в корне

Вот вам и ответ. Apache сначала проверяет наличие папки/файла, а уж потом реврайтит всё на пых.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, спасибо за ответ. Я с .htaccess не сильно дружу. А как сделать, чтоб он игнорировал поиск файла, если не указано расширение? Просто примерно на 5 машинах такого не выкидывало.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, А не проще ли переименовать файл?

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, наверно не проще. Это ExtJS. В этом файле описан класс OnlineRequest. ExtJS динамически подгружает его, когда встречает незнакомый класс. И подгружает по имени файла. Т.е. это придется во всех местах изменить имя этого класса.  
Ну да ладно. На хостинге вроде нормально работает. Просто остается загадкой почему он так делает. На 5 остальных компах нормально работает. Видимо что-то в конфиге апача не то.